# Explicit StreamPoint

Tags: plotting

I have trouble with getting the explicit initial StreamPoint to work. 
The number of streamlines are not the same as the number of initial points. What am I doing wrong?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
KDIM = 178.2;
KDNA = 9900;
n = 7;
b1 = 1.6;
b4 = 0.003;
b3 = b4/10;
b2 = (b1 + b3)/2;
b1 = b1 - b4; b2 = b2 - b4 ; b3 = b3 - b4;

gamma1 = 0.0012;
gamma2 = 0.0012;
r2 = 2.3;
M[x1_] := (KDIM/KDNA)*((1 + (1 + (4/KDIM)*(2*x1))^(1/2))/(2*(2*x1)))^2;
Y1[x1_, x2_] := r2*x2 - gamma2*x1;
Y2[x1_, x2_] := n*((M[x1]/(1 + M[x1]*3*x1))*(b1 + b2 + b3)*x1) + n*b4 - gamma1*x2;
eqs = { Y1[x, y], Y2[x, y]};

xmin = 20000;
xmax = 50000;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 30;
points = Tuples[{Range[xmin, xmax, xmax/20],Range[ymin, ymax, ymax/5]}];
gv = VectorPlot[eqs, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorScale{Automatic, Automatic},StreamPoints -> points, StreamStyle -> {Red, "Line"},PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]
```

[image: Too Few Streamlines]![I expected to get 100 streamlines, but I am only getting 2 and they are short]

I expected to get 100 streamlines, but I am only getting 2 and they are short

Answer (score 1):

Here is it, I needed to circumvent some limitations. But I don't know why StreamPlot limits the points:

```
stp = StreamPlot[eqs, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
              StreamStyle -> {Red, "Line"}, 
              PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
              StreamPoints -> {#}] & /@ points;

Show[stp, VectorPlot[eqs, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
                    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
                    Epilog -> Point[points]]]
```

[image]